# Private functions of a class accessible?

Tags: c++, oop, class, gcc, information-hiding

I have been trying to learn C++ for some time now. Recently I came across the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point {
    private:
        double x_, y_;

    public: 
        Point(double x, double y){
            x_ = x;
            y_ = y; 
        }

        Point() {
            x_ = 0.0;
            y_ = 0.0;   
        }

        double getX(){
            return x_;  
        }

        double getY(){
            return y_;  
        }

        void setX(double x){
            x_ = x; 
        }

        void setY(double y){
            y_ = y; 
        }

        void add(Point p){
            x_ += p.x_;
            y_ += p.y_;
        }

        void sub(Point p){
            x_ -= p.x_;
            y_ -= p.y_;
        }

        void mul(double a){
            x_ *= a;
            y_ *= a;    
        }

        void dump(){
            cout << "(" << x_ << ", " << y_ << ")" << endl; 
        }
};

int main(){
    Point p(3, 1);
    Point p1(10, 5);

    p.add(p1);
    p.dump();

    p.sub(p1);
    p.dump();

    return 0;
}
```

And for the life of me I can not figure out why do the methods `void add(Point P)` and `void sub( Point p )` work.

Shouldn't I get an error like `"cannot access private properties of class Point"` or something when I try to use `add` or `sub`?

Program compiled with `gcc` version `4.6.3` `(Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`.
When run it outputs:

```
(13, 6)
 (3, 1)
```

Comment: It's part of the `Point` class, thus it can access its own private members.

Comment: How bad would it be not being able to access your own privates?

Comment: access specifier are per type not per instance. So inside a member method you can access all private members regardless if they belong to this or another instance.

Answer (score 7):

Private keyword specifies that those members are accessible only from member functions and friends of the class. Private variables are accessable by the same type of objects even from other instances of the class.

This is not about security what lot of people think. This is about hiding internal structure of the class from other codes. It is required that a class won't mess up other instances by accident, thus no point to hiding variables from other instances. (Actually that would be a bit trickier to implement, and no or little reason to do so.)

Answer (score 5):

`private` members cannot be accessed from outside of a class except for `friend`s, but can be from anywhere inside of the class.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the methods themselves because they are in the `public` section of the class definition, and they can access `private` members because they are part of the class.

```
private:
    double x_, y_;

public: 
    Point(double x, double y)
    Point() 
    double getX()
    double getY()
    void setX(double x)
    void setY(double y)
    void add(Point p)
    void sub(Point p)
    void mul(double a)
    void dump()
```

The fields in `private` can only be accessed by other class members in this case (no friends).

The `public` members can be accessed by anyone.

Comment: I think OP is asking about member variables.

Comment: @Mahesh "Shouldn't I get an error like "cannot access private properties of class Point" or something **when I try to use add or sub?**"

Comment: I think you are allowed to replace "should" with "must" . :-)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Probably I misunderstood the question. Isn't the OP doubt is about how the private variables of other object is being accessed in the current object ? Though the type of both the objects is same.

Comment: @Mahesh now that I re-read, I guess it can be interpreted both ways. Regardless, edited to reflect both aspects...

Answer (score 3):

Because the access to those variables is happening from ***within the class*** via it's methods; you are not accessing the variables directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing "class" with "object".  To put it in your way of thinking. A Object can access the private members of another object if both objects are of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Since `add(Point p)` and `sub (Point p)` are members of class `Point`, they can access private members of any instance of `Point` (in this case `p`) and not only private members of object `this`.

Answer (score -1):

You are not directly accessing the private class members. You are calling the add() and sub() method which are public methods. These *are* allowed to access the private member variables.

If you were to attempt:

```
p.x_ ++;
```

that would not be allowed, since x_ is private to the Point class

Comment: Could downvoters please comment? I can't work out what's incorrect about my answer.

Comment: You got downvotes because you didn't answer the actual question.